# RxJava: Blocking single vs Blocking first

Tags: rx-java, reactive

I could never understand the difference between `blockingSingle` and `blockingFirst` on `Observables` in RxJava. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

definitions from https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Blocking-Observable-Operators

```
first() — block until the Observable emits an item, then return the first item 
emitted by the Observable

single( ) — if the Observable completes after emitting a single item, return 
that item, otherwise throw an exception
```

sounds like `first()` immediately returns upon emitting any item, and `single()` waits for the Observable to complete to return.

Comment: More precisely, `single` and `blockingSingle` expects the source to have one item. If it has more than one, they signal an exception instead and you don't get any items.